# How to set VirtualDirectory credentials

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7.5

I'd like to set credentials for my VirtualDirectory. I have previously created user and what I do is:

```
        DirectoryEntry site = new DirectoryEntry"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root");
        string className = site.SchemaClassName.ToString();
        if ((className.EndsWith("Server")) || (className.EndsWith("VirtualDir")))
        {
            DirectoryEntries vdirs = site.Children;
            DirectoryEntry existingDirectoryEntry = vdirs.OfType<DirectoryEntry>().SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name == name);
            if (existingDirectoryEntry != null)
                throw new Exception("The virtual directory you want to create already exists");

            DirectoryEntry newVDir = vdirs.Add(name, (className.Replace("Service", "VirtualDir")));
            newVDir.Username = username;
            newVDir.Password = password;
            newVDir.Properties["Path"][0] = path;
            newVDir.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = true;
            if (authFlags.HasValue)
                newVDir.Properties["AuthFlags"].Value = authFlags.Value;

            newVDir.CommitChanges();
        }
```

Without setting username and password directory is created correctly. When I set username and password I receive message that system cannot find the specified path, but path exists. Maybe I should change somehow authentication type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. In this case username and password should be set via properties and not directly in object:

```
newVDir.Properties["UNCUserName"][0] = username;
newVDir.Properties["UNCPassword"][0] = password;
```

And that solved my problem.